# Android Studio suddenly can't find ANY drawable components

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Like the title suggests, all of a sudden, my Android Studio projects simply can't locate any of my drawable resources that I call when using `android:background="@drawable/serving_editor_background"` for example, it'll just give me this error code for every single drawable that has been called:

```
AAPT: error: resource drawable/serving_editor_background (aka com.example.poop123:drawable/serving_editor_background) not found.
```

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException (no error message)
```

```
ParseError at [row,col]:[2,6]
Message: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
```

It literally does it for every single one (with their respective names and file path), all of the ones that used to work up until now, not a single one works, and I never changed anything in the gradle, but I'll still provide it:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.poop123"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation:chip-navigation-bar:1.3.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabstrip:navigationtabstrip:+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    compileOnly 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.6.0'
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.poop123">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Poop123">
        <activity android:name=".EditAddition"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ConfirmAddition" />
        <activity android:name=".Goal" />
        <activity android:name=".ActivityLevel" />
        <activity android:name=".newFoodMenu" />
        <activity android:name=".foodLibrary" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm getting really frustrated at this, because I changed absolutely nothing (just a specific XML code for a certain activity), and now none of the drawables can be found.
If any more info, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bascially, I loaded up an old version of the project, copy pasted all the new code into the current project, noticed that on one of the drawable's, I had an extra

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

And for some reason it completely clogged up the whole thing, and the exception messages it gave, had 0 to do with it in a sense, had to manually find the problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all locate the drawable folder of your project and see the resources. if you found the resources try android:src="@drawable/resource"